# How can I set the colors on a plotly sunburst chart using the graph_objects submodule?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

If I’m using the plotly express submodule, I can create a colored sunburst chart in the following way:

```
import plotly.express as px


names = ["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"]
parents = ["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" ]
values = [10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4]
color_discrete_sequence = ['#2D5F91', '#FFAA00', '#96BEE6', '#48B7B4', '#E8655F',
                           '#819FBD', '#FFCC66', '#C0D8F0', '#91D4D2', '#F1A39F']

fig = px.sunburst(
    names=names,
    parents=parents,
    values=values,
    color_discrete_sequence = color_discrete_sequence,
)
fig.show()
```

I would like to do the same with plotly’s graph_objects. Is there a similar functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `graph_objects` version is available in [the official reference](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/).

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

color_discrete_sequence = ['', '#FFAA00', '#2D5F91','#819FBD','#819FBD','#91D4D2', '#96BEE6', '#C0D8F0','#E8655F','#F1A39F','#48B7B4']

fig =go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
    labels=\["Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"\],
    parents=\["", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve" \],
    values=\[10, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4\],
    marker=dict(colors=color_discrete_sequence)
))
# Update layout for tight margin
# See https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/
fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=0, l=0, r=0, b=0))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: In contrast to the `express` version, the `graph_objects` version unfortunately does not have the property `color_discrete_sequence`. At least I cannot find it.

Comment: Thank you! That works nearly perfect. There is just one small difference that remains. In the `express` module the parents inherit their colors to their children—what looks way better. Is there an option which provides that feature? Or do I have to set the colors manually?

Comment: I'm not sure why the colors are different, but I was able to manually align it with the PX.

Comment: In order to have the same color as the parent, the length of the list `color_discrete_sequence` should be the same as the number of parents. For instance, if you have three parents, you can only specify three colors in the `color_discrete_sequence` list. In that case, the colors of the parents are inherited by their children nodes.